# PermissionError trying to access Desktop from Python on MacOS (either shutil or os.chdir())

Tags: python, shutil

I have a mac computer and am trying to use the basic copy or move functions from the Shutil library.

Whenever I run the code, the console prints an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/ryanyee/Desktop/scr/CC_Info - Alex - 8'
```

or something similar to that error.

**Here is my code below:**

```
import shutil, os

source = "/Users/ryanyee/Desktop/scr/CC_Info - Alex - 8"
destination = "/Users/ryanyee/Desktop/dest"

shutil.copy(source,destination)
```

The code should copy that single file from the scr folder to the dest folder.

I have tried to change the directory and print the directory using:

```
os.chdir('/Users/ryanyee/Desktop/scr')

print(os.getcwd())
```

This is the error I get when I use that:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: FYI -- it needs to be backticks, not forward ticks, to start and end code segments.

Comment: ...that said, a PermissionError comes from your operating system. It's not a problem with your code, necessarily, at all -- for example, if you're running MacOS Catalina, it could mean you didn't choose to give the terminal program or IDE you're running Python in access to your Desktop when prompted.

Comment: I am pretty new to understanding paths etc.  I looked up how to give access to my desktop and read about os.expanduser().  If I use that function, would I run the entire path name through the function?  Or just Path.home()?  Do you know other ways to give access to my desktop?  I am working through spyder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my current working directory was saving the documents to the same folder that my code was stored.

To fix the code, I had to have the document in the same folder that the script was saved in.

Comment: The solution was to save the document in the same folder as the script, yet the issue was that _my current working directory was saving the documents to the same folder that my code was stored_ ? How does that work?

Comment: Since the document is saved in the same folder as your script, your script is able to find your script easily without searching for different directories that lead to your document.